# change the color of ui-select multiple place holder

Tags: ui-select

I'm trying t change the color of the place holder in

```css
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<ui-select ng-model="model.selected">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...I want to change this color">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | filter: $select.search track by person.name">
        <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You must prefix the selector to the various browsers:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: red;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: red;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it 
by putting the `::-webkit-input-placeholder`

on the direct element